# C++ Insert result of permutations into a vector

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lambda

I am encountering the issue that the first result of the permutation is being entered into the vector, but on the next `for_each` loop iteration the size of the vector resets itself to `{size = 0}`, instead of increasing its size and inserting the second permutation, and so on. How do I get around this? I've tried using a while loop but I couldn't work out what the condition for it should be.

I also wanted to ask, as later on I will need to compare the values in this vector to a vector containing a dictionary, would the current code (when working correctly) allow me to do so.

This is my code so far:

```
for_each(permutations.begin(), permutations.end(), [](string stringPermutations)
{
    vector<string> permutations;
    permutations.push_back(stringPermutations);
    cout << stringPermutations << endl;
});
```

So apparently it looks like the lambda always creates a new, local, vector each time it's called. If I place `vector<string> permutations;` outside of the lambda I get an error with `permutations.push_back(stringPermutations);`. So how do I go about retrieving the `stringPermutations` out of the lambda and into a public accessible vector?

Thanks for the help and feedback.

Comment: Your question aside, why are you using `std::for_each`?

Comment: Your lambda creates a new, local, vector each time it's called.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you trying to build a vector of strings containing all the permutations of the string?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/permutations-of-a-given-string-using-stl/

Comment: @Mikhail yes that is what i want. I've edited my question to show more code.

Comment: @MacGenius Is it the exact code I linked to?

Comment: @Mikhail not quite, as I also need permutations that are equal to or less then the users input. eg. If the input is "asdfg" - 6 characters long, I also need permutations 4,3,2 characters long. Is the best way I can explain it.

Comment: no reason to use `std::for_each` or lambda expression here. You're making your life difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the vector outside the lambda and use [lambda capture](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) to capture this vector:

```
vector<string> permutation_v;
for_each(permutations.begin(), permutations.end(), [&](string stringPermutations)
                                                 // ^
{
    permutation_v.push_back(stringPermutations);
    cout << stringPermutations << endl;
});
```

But if I were you, I would directly construct this vector as

```
vector<string> permutation_v{permutations.begin(), permutations.end()};
```

Comment: So simple, it's perfect. It's always the most simplest things that often trip you up...

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you want to achieve with your code, but it just seems you want to print the contents of `permutations`.
Then just look at the elements in the vector.

```
for (auto &permutation : permutations) std::cout << permutation << '\n';
```

The question is: why do you use an `std::unordered_set<std::string>` and not a `std::vector<std::string>` in the first place? then you do not need to copy the elements into a new vector.